# how to repeat an integer n, n times in a list (python)?

Tags: python, list

How would I go about repeating an integer n, n times within a list? for example:

```
[1,2,3] --> [1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Please read [ask].

Comment: it's for a project. I'm looking at doing a for loop with np.repeat thrown in at some point

Comment: So show us what you've tried, and tell us what isn't working. And if you're using `numpy`, _tell us_. We aren't going to assume you're using something like that.

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002670.

Answer (score 6):

No need for numpy, you can just use `itertools` here.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> n = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [r for i in n for r in repeat(i, i)]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use itertools, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [e for e in l for _ in range(e)]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
data = [1,2,3]
result = []
for i in data:
  for j in range(i):
    result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [18]: from pandas.core.common import flatten                                                                                                              
In [19]: a = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                         
In [20]: c = [[x]*x for x in a]                                                                                                                              
In [21]: list(flatten(c))                                                                                                                                    
Out[21]: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```