# How to repeat the numbers in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
 A = [1,6,3,8,5,5,2,1,2,10]
```

I want to repeat the numbers in this like:

```
A = [1,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,..... so on]
```

i.e 1 repeat once, 6 repeat six times, 3 repeat thrice and so on....

I tried with:

```
B=np.concatenate([([x]*x) for x in A], axis=0)
```

but it multiplying the corresponding number and I am getting this result:

```
  B = [1,36,36,36,36,36,36,9,9,9,.....so on]
```

when I am doing:

```
B=np.concatenate([([x]*3) for x in A], axis=0)
```

this giving me:

```
B = [1,1,6,6,3,3,8,8... so on]
```

what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use nested loop

```py
l  = [1, 6, 3]
nl = []
for number in l:
    for i in range(number):
        nl.append(number)
print(nl)
```

or using list comprehension

```py
l = [1,6,3]
nl = [number  for number in l for i in range(number)]
#[1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can perform this operation using `numpy` without using a `for` loop.

`np.repeat(a, repeats)` will repeat the input array `a` according to `repeats` which specify the number of repetitions for each element.

```
import numpy as np
A = [1,6,3,8,5,5,2,1,2,10]
B = np.repeat(A,A)
```

Output:

```
>>> array([ 1,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  3,  3,  3,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
    8,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  2,  2,  1,  2,  2, 10,
   10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the repeat function of NumPy you can get the solution

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(A, A)
```

Answer (score 3):

hello you can make this with the lib itertools:

```
import itertools
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, x) for x in lst)) 
#[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of integers, to which the multiplication means arithmetic multiplication. You need to convert them into strings.

```
A = [1,6,3,8,5,5,2,1,2,10]
new_A = [x * str(x) for x in A]
```

which is called list comprehension, being a much cleaner/pythonic way of:

```
for x in A:
new_A.append(x * str(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
B = np.concatenate([[a]*a for a in A])

>>> array([ 1,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  3,  3,  3,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
    8,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  2,  2,  1,  2,  2, 10,
   10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nums = [1, 5, 4]
res = []
for num in nums:
    res.extend([num] * num)
print(res)
# [1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```